Best way to display two variables changing over the span of a number of years?
I'm trying to display both the median rent in a city as well as its population on the y axis in relationship to the year in the x axis.
On first instinct I'd go with a bubble chart, where the y axis corresponds to population, the x-axis to year, and where each bubble's volume correlates to the median rent. But that visually obfuscates the value of population in relationship to the year.
Are there better ways to do this?

What are you trying to communicate with this figure?

@mkt I'm trying to reflect the way that a fast growing population in the city (with stagnant housing development) leads to higher median rent prices

Why not show your data? Then people so minded can experiment and show you their ideas in action?

If at all, using the population as the bubble size probably makes more sense.
Alternatively, plot one series and encode the other one by color (e.g., a heated body palette) or grayscale.
Finally, you could simply try plotting two time series with two different vertical axes. This is most likely what I would do.
Try different methods and see which one works best.

If your goal is to show that fast growing population leads to higher median rent prices, why not simply plot rent prices (y axis) as a function of population size (x). And in fact not absolute rent prices, but relative rent change (% change), and not as a function of total populaton in the city, but of relative population increase (% change in population).
Do this where $Year_0$ is at the origin (0,0). The next point will be say at (10,5) (if the population grew by 10%, and the median rent by 5%). The next point (for the next year) may then be at (15,4) because the population grew by another 5%, but the median rent dropped by 1%. Etc, for all years in your dataset.
Note that the year here is sort of a confounding variable; it is not really part of the point you are trying to make. It is just that each new year you get a new data point. And, if you have the data, you could do the same plot by quarter, or even by month...
You may also do the same type of plot, but with absolute values (as opposed to relative changes). Or you can do it with relative changes, but wrt $Year_0$, as opposed to relative year-to-year change. I just have a feel that relative changes will be more eloquent (a 100,000 change in population is not the same for a large or a small city; nor is a $100 increase in rent the same in a high cost of living city than in a low cost of living city). And that y2y changes may better tell your story. But you can try all 3, and see which is the most "eloquent" for your point (as we all know that a good graph is worth 1000 words...).
